# JavaFX 3D - Is it possible to change the width of Line in DrawMode.Line?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-3d

I would like to change the **linewidth** of any mesh with **DrawMode.*LINE***, but I don't know if it is possible.

I added some code for reference.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    PerspectiveCamera camera= new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 768, true);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    camera.setFarClip(10000);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-10);
    scene.setCamera(camera);

    Box box  = new Box();
    box.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
    root.getChildren().addAll(camera,box);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: I don't think so.  There is not API to set the width of the wireframe lines.  The only way I can think of, is to try to fudge it by, for instance, rendering the 3D scene at half size, then scaling it up by a factor of. for example 2, to double the width of the lines.  I'm not sure if that would work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. The `DrawMode` is passed down to the native renderer whose default wireframe is a width 1 line. For the Direct3D pipeline, see [Outline and Fill State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/outline-and-fill-state). Even if you use the [line drawing support library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/line-drawing-support-in-d3dx) it will tell you that:

> The library uses native hardware line drawing support (if available in
>   the device) only if:
>
> - Line width is 1.
> - No line pattern is enabled.

Line widths that are different than 1 cannot be drawn with [line primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/primitives), but have to be drawn with triangles instead:

> The line drawing library emulates lines using texture triangles

In other words, a width of 1 is special because it has specific hardware support.